Azure ML- Deployment failing with ACI
I am trying to deploy a image classification model using azure machine learning studio.
As pre-step process, i can see the workspace creation, model registration, environment creation, inference creation succeed.
Below is the snippet code i tried

import os
import json
import requests

from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice, Webservice
from azureml.exceptions import WebserviceException

def config_deploy_source():
    config_file_path = "config.json"
    # Read JSON data into a dictionary
    with open(config_file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    config_data = {
        'subscription_id': data["subscription_id"],
        'resource_group': data["resource_group"],
        'workspace_name': data["workspace_name"],
        'region': data["region"]
    }
    return config_data

def create_workspace():
    service_data = config_deploy_source()
    
    print(service_data)
    ws = Workspace.create(name=service_data['workspace_name'],
                            subscription_id=service_data['subscription_id'],
                            resource_group=service_data['resource_group'],
                            location=service_data['region'])
    print(f'Workspace {service_data["workspace_name"]} created')
    
    return ws

def register_model(ws):
    model_path = 'man_woman_model.pth'
    model_name = 'man_woman_classific_model'
    registered_model = Model.register(model_path=model_path, model_name=model_name, workspace=ws)
    print(f'Model {model_name} registered.')
    return registered_model
  
  
  

def create_env():
    conda_env = Environment(name="my-env")
    conda_deps = CondaDependencies()
    conda_deps.add_channel("pytorch")
    conda_deps.add_pip_package("torch")
    conda_deps.add_pip_package("torchvision")
    conda_deps.add_conda_package("numpy")
    conda_deps.add_conda_package("pandas")
    conda_deps.add_conda_package("scikit-learn")
    conda_env.python.conda_dependencies = conda_deps
    return conda_env
  
  
def create_inference(conda_env):
    inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='score.py', environment=conda_env)
    print('Inference configuration created.')
    return inference_config

def deploy_model(ws, registered_model, inference_config):
    aci_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, memory_gb=1)
    service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                           name='man-woman-classify-service',
                           models=[registered_model],
                           inference_config=inference_config,
                           deployment_config=aci_config)
    service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
    scoring_uri = service.scoring_uri
    print(f"Model deployed at {scoring_uri}")
    return scoring_uri

def main():
    # Configure, create workspace, and register the model
    ws = create_workspace()
    registered_model = register_model(ws)
    conda_env = create_env()
    inference_config = create_inference(conda_env)
    
    # Deploy the model and get the scoring URI
    try:
      
      scoring_uri = deploy_model(ws, registered_model, inference_config)
      print(f"Deployed model endpoint: {scoring_uri}")
    except WebserviceException as e:
      service = Webservice(workspace=ws, name='man-women-classify-service')
      print("Issue due to ", service.get_logs())
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Below is the score.py'
import json
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
from azureml.core.model import Model
import io
import base64

# Define the same model structure as during training
class SimpleCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 64 * 64, 128)  # Assuming image size is 128x128 after pooling
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 1)  # Binary classification (man vs woman)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 64 * 64)  # Flatten
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fc2(x))
        return x

# Global variable for the model
model = None

# This function initializes the model (loading it from the serialized file)
def init():
    global model
    # Load the model
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('man_woman_classific_model') 
    model = SimpleCNN()
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode

# Preprocessing: Define transformations that must be applied to the input image
def preprocess_image(image_bytes):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((128, 128)),  # Resize the image to match model input size
        transforms.ToTensor(),          # Convert the image to a tensor
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))  # Normalize the image
    ])
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))  # Read the image bytes
    return transform(image).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

# Run inference and return the output
def run(raw_data):
    try:
        data = json.loads(raw_data)

        image_bytes = base64.b64decode(data['image'])

        input_tensor = preprocess_image(image_bytes)

        with torch.no_grad():
            output = model(input_tensor)
        prediction = "woman" if output.item() > 0.5 else "man"
        return json.dumps({"prediction": prediction})
    
    except Exception as e:
        result = str(e)
        return json.dumps({"error": result})


what i am expecting is to deploy the model and create the end point to access the model in downstream application.
I can see the model is registered in the workspace.
Now during the model deployment stage, iam getting below error
{
  "code": "AciDeploymentFailed",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Aci Deployment failed with exception: Error in entry script, RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:
        {}'.format(, please run print(service.get_logs()) to get details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "CrashLoopBackOff",
      "message": "Error in entry script, RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:
        {}'.format(, please run print(service.get_logs()) to get details."

Is there any better way to do this or any solution?

Add the log details.
